# How to change the language on name picker buttons

Tags: xpages

I would like to modify the language text on the extenstion library's name picker buttons.

[image: Name picker]

I found this tip http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_Extension_Library  but it did not work for me with 8.53 and IE8.

Does anyone have a work around ?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<title>Groupe</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/css/2Ojcore.css&amp;2Ojdojo.css&amp;2OldefaultTheme.css&amp;2OldojoTheme.css&amp;@Da&amp;@Ib&amp;@Th&amp;@Ti&amp;@Tj.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="locale: 'fr-ca', parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.registerModulePath('extlib', '/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib');</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/dojo/.fr-ca/@EOb&amp;@EOf&amp;@Ek&amp;@Eya.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/EIJ%20852.nsf/Required.css">
</head>
<body class="xsp lotusui tundra">
<form id="view:_id1" method="post" action="/EIJ%20852.nsf/xAdminGestionAccesGroupeDetails.xsp" class="lotusForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<script>[| dojo.provide("yn.dijit.PickerName");
dojo.declare(
"yn.dijit.PickerName", [extlib.dijit.OneUIPickerName], {
postMixInProperties: function() {
this.inherited(arguments);
var t = this.templateString;
// change text in HTML
t = t.replace(/Search for/, 'Rechercher pour');
// change button labels, add ">" in regex to make sure to select a button and nothing else
// the "g" option in the regex leads to javascript errors at runtime
t = t.replace(/>Search/, '>Rechercher');
t = t.replace(/>Add/, '>Ajouter');
t = t.replace(/>Remove/, '>Retirer');
t = t.replace(/>Remove All/, '>Retirer tout');
t = t.replace(/>Cancel/, '>Annuler');
this.templateString = t;
}
}); ]</script><script>[| var ynXSPSelectValue = XSP.selectValue;
XSP.selectValue = function(t, vars) {
if (t == "extlib.dijit.OneUIPickerName") {
ynXSPSelectValue("yn.dijit.PickerName", vars);
} else {
ynXSPSelectValue(t, vars);
}
} ]</script><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

The labels on the dialog are automatically changed according to the language that is used in the browser. Julian's solution still works for me.
If you want to have it in a more elegant way, you have to do a little Java to not only use the browser language but let the user change the language
This can be done using a variable resolver. The trick is to set the "locale" on the view root at every change or reload of the page. This one http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=649 should give you an idea, how this will look like.
I have some problems with the extLib from OpenNTF. Some of the localization packages seems not to be implemented correct. So I still see english labels even if I choose a different language. But this is a known issue and has been fixed in the upgrade pack.

Comment: Thanks I will try the upgrade pack first

Comment: I uninstalled the extension library and installed the upgrade pack.  But that caused errors as I used xe:dialogcontent in my app.

Comment: I uninstalled the upgrade pack and reinstalled the extension library and retried Julian Buss's solution and I noticed that he referenced extlib.dijit.PickerName.  In Firefox I noticed that the name picker is called XSP.selectValue('extlib.dijit.OneUIPickerName'.  So I changed his code PickerName --> OneUIPickerName.  But it still is not working.  I'm new to xPages and am pretty sure that it's a simple thing.  Any ideas.  Thanks